# JPEG compression benchmark on Cortex M4

Tags: stm32, imageprocessing, image-sensor, cortex-m4

I am currently using an STM32F4xx and extracting an already compressed JPEG from a camera module OV5645 as that particular sensor has an internal JPEG codec. I want to starting using a new sensor, OV8865, that does not come with the internal codec and I wonder if it is feasible to use a STM32 MCU in order to extract the RAW RGB and encode it into a JPEG getting at least 2 frames per second. I can't use the [Digital camera interface (DCMI) for STM32 MCUs](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00373474-digital-camera-interface-dcmi-on-stm32-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) built into the STM32F4 as the maximum input size is 2048 × 2048 pixels and I'd like to use at least the resolution of 2816 x 1584 pixels the sensor offers (*although 3264 x 2448 would be better*).

Is there any estimation on how long it would take to a Cortex M4 such as STM32F4xx to encode a 2816 x 1584 or a full 8MP image (3264 x 2448).

I wonder if a MCU is enough for 2 fps.

Do you know any comercial IC that encodes RAW RGB into JPEG? I guess I could design an FPGA but it will be out of the scope of the scale of the project.

Comment: I think there is no hope for normal jpeg, since x86 CPU cores often don't do more than 50-100 MP/s. However, you could try stripping jpeg to a minimum (no YCbCr, trivial huffman coding, etc which I believe are technically allowed) and see how fast you can get it if you don't mind very poor compression.

Answer (score 2):

> I wonder if a MCU is enough for 2 fps.

STM32F7/H7 has a [hardware jpeg compression peripheral](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00356635-hardware-jpeg-codec-peripheral-in-stm32f7677xxx-and-stm32h743534555475750a3b3b0xx-microcontrollers-stmicroelectronics.pdf) that only takes 4 ms to compress a 640x480 image. However converting the image from RGB to the required YCbCr format takes ~60 ms at 400 MHz, equating to a total time of ~900 ms for converting 2816x1584. I expect an STM32F4 with encoding done purely in software would be much slower.

> Do you know any comercial IC that encodes RAW RGB into JPEG? I guess I
> could design an FPGA but it will be out of the scope of the scale of
> the project.

I couldn't find any chips designed to do your specific format, but I did find several FPGA encoder cores. [Here's one](https://opencores.org/projects/mkjpeg) that claims 7.3 ms processing time for 640x480 with a 100 MHz clock, which equates to ~100 ms at 2816x1584.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I tested a grayscale jpeg software encoder on a NXP LPC2388 and then on an LPC1778 both running at 48 MHz.

The CMOS camera was Omnivision OV7676 (0.3 Megapixel 640×480).

I used chrominance samples only, that is Y, because as said I tested a gray scale software encoder.

I was able to get a frame rate of 2 fps on LPC2388 an 5 fps on LPC1778.

---

The main problems I got were:

1. Shortage of memory

I wasn't able to store in RAM an entire frame because I had 64 kbytes only. So I had to store the whole frame in an external flash memory and then encode it.

2. I didn't have floating point unit

The algorithm was very slow because JPEG encoding has a lot of multiplications inside.

To speed up operations, I modified the algorithm in order to use integer arithmetic.

It worked well without any appreciable quality loss.

The file size though increased by 10% at least because some internal predefined matrix coefficients were calculated 30 years ago by the JPEG consortium, using floating point multiplications.

---

Later in the afternoon I will post here the Github repo of that software encoder because I don't have it handy.

---

I modified the algorithm using Microsoft Visual Studio because it's really fast and then tested it on the 2 embedded platforms.